# How to Add and Delete Instance of autoscaling group using Shell Script?

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, scripting, influxdb

Hi I have written a shell script which I'm using to make entries of my meta-nodes and data-nodes of InfluxDb Interprise .

```
 "#!/bin/bash"
          MPIP=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`
          MPDNS=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname`
          wget https://dl.influxdata.com/enterprise/releases/influxdb-meta-1.6.4_c1.6.4.x86_64.rpm
          sudo yum localinstall influxdb-meta-1.6.4_c1.6.4.x86_64.rpm
          sed -i -e "s/#hostname/hostname=$MPDNS/g" /etc/influxdb/influxdb-meta.conf
          sed -i -e 's/license-key/license-key = xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-421f-svjdsv-shhjhvbavajh/g' /etc/influxdb/influxdb-meta.conf
          service influxdb-meta start
          ##Adding Master instances
          influxd-ctl add-meta "$MPDNS":8091
          sudo yum install -qqy wget xfsprogs xfsdump mdadm docker\n"
          aws configure set default.region
          !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          ## Adding Meta Node 
          export INSTANCEID=`aws  autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups  --auto-scaling-group-name Influxdb-metaAsg| grep INSTANCES | cut -f4`
          for i in $INSTANCEID 
          do
          export DNS=`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id=$i | grep PRIVATEIPADDRESSES | cut -f3`
          'influxd-ctl add-meta $DNS:8091'
          done
    ## Adding Data Node 
          export INSTANCEID=`aws  autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups  --auto-scaling-group-name Influxdb-dataAsg| grep INSTANCES | cut -f4`
          for i in $INSTANCEID 
          do
          export DNS=`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id=$i | grep PRIVATEIPADDRESSES | cut -f3`
          'influxd-ctl add-data $DNS:8088'
```

Now what happen whenever there is one new instance spin up in my influxDB cluster and get terminated once the load come below 60 % it entires remains in InfluxDB-meta.conf .

I want to get that entries removed once the instance get down .

Please help me to achieve that.

Comment: MySQL InfluxDB-meta.conf - ? A typo? Or did you mean anything special?

Comment: My apologies it was Influxdb-meta.conf